# ReactJS CSS: "Unexpected token, expected ;"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've added a css file to my ReactJS page.

The styling works perfectly fine when I run the App using "npm start", however when I make the production build with "npm run build" I'm getting the following error:

```
"Unexpected token, expected ;"
```

[image]

```
 react-authentication-frontend@1.0.0 lint C:\Users\Simon\Documents\GitHub\videoinwerken\react_frontend
> eslint ./src ./tests

Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .
You are using a whole package of antd, please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import to reduce app bundle size.
C:\Users\Simon\Documents\GitHub\videoinwerken\react_frontend\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/GitHub/videoinwerken/react_frontend/src/components/Pages/Employer/Employees/AddEmployees/style.css: Unexpected token, expected ; (2:5)
  1 | html,
> 2 | body {
    |      ^
  3 |   width: 100%;
  4 |   height: 100%;
  5 | }
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Users\Simon\Documents\GitHub\videoinwerken\react_frontend\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
```

See my code below

**SomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./style.css";

export default class ExcelPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>hello, this page is broken</div>;
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'm running the following webpack config:

**Webpack**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const DEV = !PROD;
const DevToolPlugin = PROD
    ? webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin
    : webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin;

const config = {
    entry: ["./src/index"],
    output: {
        filename: DEV ? "bundle.js" : "bundle.[hash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 20000
                        }
                    },
                    "image-webpack-loader"
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: true,
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new DevToolPlugin({
            filename: "[file].map"
        })
    ], 
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
};

!PROD && (config.devtool = 'source-map');

PROD && config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compressor: {
            warnings: false,
        }
    })
);

PROD && config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    })
);

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-authentication-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Authentication Frontend",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/ZachLiuGIS/reactjs-auth-django-rest",
  "homepage": "/videoinwerken/",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "lint": "eslint ./src ./tests",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run test && webpack --progress --profile --colors",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 8083",
    "test": "npm run lint && mocha --require babel-register ./tests/setup.js --recursive ./tests/**/*.spec.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "Zach Liu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.12.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "antd": "^3.20.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "dnd-core": "^2.6.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "^2.1.4",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.13",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-excel-renderer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-player": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.3",
    "redux-form-validators": "^2.7.5",
    "redux-notifications": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    [
      "env"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222979/discussion-on-question-by-sj19-reactjs-css-unexpected-token-expected).